# How to use Zf2 translate withot textdomain?

Tags: translation, zend-framework2

My module works fine with

```
'translator' => array(  'locale' => 'de_DE',
            'translation_file_patterns' => array(
                    array(
                    'type'     => 'gettext',
                    'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                    'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
```

Only when i use MO files like DE.mo EN.mo but when files are en_US.mo , de_DE.mo i need to add to congik `'text_domain' => __NAMESPACE__` , and in my view `$this->translate('some message',__NAMESPACE__)`
How i can escape this difference?

Comment: If, DE.mo and EN.mo work fine for you, why change em? ;) I don't know of a way without using text-domain, though you could always write your own view-helper...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** use text domains, but they are not obligatory. So:

```
'translator' => array('locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
)
```

And in your view script:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('My Foo'); ?>
```

**If** you use a text domain, then you **must** use them in both the configuration **and** the view helper:

```
'translator' => array('locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'        => 'gettext',
            'base_dir'    => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'     => '%s.mo',
            'text_domain' => 'domain-1'
        ),
    ),
)
```

Then you **must** do this:

```
<?php 
    $this->plugin('translate')->setTranslatorTextDomain('domain-1');
    echo $this->translate('My Foo') 
?>
```

But either way are possible. It is not the case you need to use text domains for specific locales.